# How to mask a password in a VSTO backstage view?

Tags: vsto

I need to put a password input into a custom backstage tab of my VSTO solution. How can I mask the password? The Edit Box doesn't seem to support this, or does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ribbon controls are generally much more limiting than standard .NET controls, so no, it doesn't support special password characters.

The best way to get around this while remaining in the backstage view is by placing the actual characters in somewhere like the `Tag` of the `EditBox` and putting placeholder password characters in the `Text` property, then devising a way to sync the two when the `TextChanged` event is fired.

Comment: +1 for confirming that there is no support for this in the ribbon UI. However, I doubt that it is possible to implement the suggested sync approach. The onChange-callback of the EditBox is fired only on loosing focus, not with every key stroke. (You mention a TextChanged event - did you mean the callback, or do I miss something?) It hands over the entire string, which makes it difficult to extract the entered character. (And the Tag property in IRibbonControl is read-only, but that wouldn't hurt.) Nevertheless I'm going to accept the answer if nobody gives a better one by Monday. Thank you!

Comment: @Matthias: Yeah, you're right about it only changing on losing focus. The other issues stem from my unfamiliarity with `RibbonXML` - I tend to restrict myself to the visual designer. So, supposing a .NET popup form is out of the question, best of luck to you!

Comment: The popup solution isn't welcome at all (it's kind of a break, after all, and I posted this question to prevent it), but feasible - so that's what I've eventually implemented.